# Referencia indefinida de funções

Tags: c, header

Tenho um problema relacionado a modularização do meu projeto. Não liguem muito para a lógica do programa, porque o maior problema que enfrento é o fato do programa não compilar. Acho que o problema reside na *linkagem* entre os arquivos *source* e *header* mas não tenho certeza.

Os arquivos do projeto estão abaixo.

```
// main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "geometria.h"
#include "interface.h"


int main(void){

char carac ;
unsigned valor, raio, altura , lado1, lado2;

Apresentacao();

printf("***MENU DE OPCOES***\n");
printf("1-Area de um circulo\n");
printf("2-Volume de um cilindro\n");
printf("3-Volume de um cone\n");
printf("4-Area de um retangulo\n");
printf("5-sair do programa\n");

scanf("%u", &valor);

valor = LeOpcao( 1, 5 );

valor = LeValor();

while( valor != 5 ) {

    printf("\nOvalor lido foi : %u\n", valor);

    carac = (char) valor;

    switch( valor ){

        case '1': printf("Digite o valor do raio: ");
        scanf("%u", &raio);
        printf("\n\nA area do circulo e %u\n", AreaCirculo( raio ) ) ;
        break;

        case '2': printf("Digite o valor do raio: ");
        scanf("%u\n", &raio);
        printf("Digite o valor da altura: ");
        scanf("%u", &altura);
        printf("\n\nO Volume do cilindro e de %u\n", VolumeCilindro( raio ,altura ));
        break;

        case '3': printf("Digite o valor do raio: ");
        scanf("%u", &raio);
        printf("Digite o valor da altura: ");
        scanf("%u", &altura);
        printf("\n\nO Volume do cilindro e de %u\n", VolumeCone( raio ,altura ));
        break;

        default: printf("Didite o valor do primeiro lado: ");
        scanf("%u\n", &lado1);
        printf("Didite o valor do segundo lado: ");
        scanf("%u", &lado2);
        printf("\n\nA area do quadrado e de %u ", AreaRetangulo( lado1 , lado2 ));

    }


}

return 0;

}
```

.

```
//geometria.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "geometria.h"

static unsigned area, volume ;

unsigned AreaCirculo( unsigned raio ){

area = 2*3,14*raio*raio ;

return area;

}

unsigned VolumeCilindro( unsigned  raio , unsigned altura ){

volume = 2*3,14*raio*raio*altura ;

return volume;

}

unsigned VolumeCone( unsigned raio , unsigned altura ){

volume = 2*3,14*raio*raio*altura/3 ;

return volume;

}

unsigned AreaRetangulo( unsigned lado1 , unsigned lado2 ){

area = lado1*lado2 ;

return area;

}
```

.

```
//geometria.h

#ifndef GEOMETRIA_H_INCLUDED
#define GEOMETRIA_H_INCLUDED


unsigned AreaCirculo( unsigned raio );

unsigned VolumeCilindro( unsigned  raio , unsigned altura );

unsigned VolumeCone( unsigned raio , unsigned altura );

unsigned AreaRetangulo( unsigned lado1 , unsigned lado2 );


#endif // GEOMETRIA_H_INCLUDED
```

.

```
// interface.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "interface.h"

void LimpaBuffer(void){

    int valorLido;

    do{
        valorLido = getchar();
    } while ((valorLido != '\n') && (valorLido != EOF));

}


void ApresentaMenu( int nItens , int menorOpcao , ... ){

    int i;
    va_list argumentos;

    /*inicia lista de argumentos variáveis*/


    va_start ( argumentos , menorOpcao );


    for( i =0 ; i < nItens ; ++i ){

        printf("%c-%s", menorOpcao++ , va_arg(argumentos, char * ) );

    }

    va_end(argumentos);



}


void Apresentacao(void){

    printf("\n\n\n");

    printf("***GEOMETRIA***");

    printf("\n\n\n");

    printf(" Esse programa tem como proposito fazer calculo de uma serie ");
    printf("de opcoes apresentadas abaixo no menu. \n\n");

}


int LeOpcao( int menorValor, int maiorValor ){

    int op;

    while(1){

        if( op >= menorValor && op <= maiorValor ){

            LimpaBuffer();
            break;
        }

        else{

            printf("\nOpcao invalida. Tente Novamente.");
            printf("\nA opcao deve estar entre %c e %c.\n", menorValor,    maiorValor);

            LimpaBuffer();

        }

    }


}

long unsigned LeValor(void){

    long valor;
    unsigned teste;

    teste = scanf("%ld", &valor);

    while( !teste || valor < 0 ){

        if(teste){

            printf("\nO valor %ld nao e valido", valor);

        }

        else{

        printf("\nO valor introduzido nao e valido");

        }

        printf("\nIntroduza um numero maior que zero: ");
        LimpaBuffer();
        teste = scanf("%ld", &valor);

    }

    LimpaBuffer();

    return valor;

}
```

.

```
//Interface.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED

void LimpaBuffer(void);

void ApresentaMenu( int nItens , int menorOpcao , ... );

void Apresentacao(void);

int LeOpcao( int menorValor, int maiorValor );

long  unsigned LeValor(void);

#endif // INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

Ja tentei de tudo para resolver os seguintes problemas apresntados abaixo. Todos relacionados a funções importadas para o arquivo main.c.

```
$ ls
bin          geometria.cbp     geometria.layout  main.c
geometria    geometria.depend  interface.c       main.cpp
geometria.c  geometria.h       interface.h       obj

$ gcc -o testit main.c
/tmp/cccNrsAz.o: na função `main':
main.c:(.text+0x18): referência indefinida para `Apresentacao'
main.c:(.text+0x79): referência indefinida para `LeOpcao'
main.c:(.text+0x7e): referência indefinida para `LeValor'
main.c:(.text+0xe9): referência indefinida para `AreaCirculo'
main.c:(.text+0x158): referência indefinida para `VolumeCilindro'
main.c:(.text+0x1c7): referência indefinida para `VolumeCone'
main.c:(.text+0x233): referência indefinida para `AreaRetangulo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Não sei qual é o real problema que envolve a *linkagen* de arquivos *source* e *header*. No momento estou usando o Code Blocks, mas já tentei criar em arquivos separados (fora do projeto do IDE, pelo gedit) e *linka*-los pelo console, só que sem sucesso.

Comment: O real problema é que o primeiro programa de todo mundo é algo simples, só o `main()`, em um arquivo. Aí vai acrescentando coisas aos poucos e vendo o que acontece. É assim que se aprende. É assim que aprende achar erros que é mais importante que escrever o código. Aí mesmo que você não consiga achar o problema fica mais fácil perguntar em algum lugar qual é o problema que está mais contido e não precisará colocar códigos longos que não importam muito para o problema.

Comment: Você mostrou vários arquivos, menos o `main.c` - que é onde o problema está ocorrendo! Tem certeza que é esse mesmo o arquivo que você quer compilar, e não o `main.cpp`?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

Experimenta compilar com:

```
gcc -o testit main.c geometria.c interface.c
```

O fato de você colocar `#include` com *headers* não faz os códigos serem incluídos também. Então você tem que indicar para o compilador todos os arquivos que contém códigos sob pena de faltar seus membros para produzir uma saída válida.

Já que você listou um código com extensão `.cpp`, se deseja compilar em C++ deverá usar o `g++` para compilar e não o `gcc`. Mas não parece ser o caso. Seu código parece ser todo C e não há necessidade de usar o compilador de C++.

Um IDE costuma chamar o compilador com todos os fontes automaticamente desde que ele saiba quais são esses arquivos. O fato de você editar um arquivo nele não o torna ciente de que este arquivo é necessário para compilar a aplicação. Você precisa criar um projeto no IDE. Este projeto conterá todas as informações necessárias para gerar a aplicação. É uma mão na roda mas não faz milagres. Você deverá dar informações fundamentais que só você sabe. Você deverá adicionar manualmente os arquivos no projeto ou criar um arquivo novo dentro do projeto para o IDE estar ciente que eles precisam ser compilados.

[Documentação](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html) e [Wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project) do CodeBlocks.

[Manual do GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

[Tutorial GCC](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bom. Esse comando não apresentou erros no console. Mas não sei como eu faço para contornar esse problema usando o code blocks, no qual apresenta o mesmo erro de depuração.

Comment: Então o problema foi resolvido, agora você tem um problema com o IDE. Já é outra questão e que você teria que detalhar essa situações específica. Você precisa criar um projeto. Em tese o IDE cuidaria da compilação se o projeto foi criado corretamente. Já leu todo o manual? http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html Wiki: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project

Comment: Realmente, pelo IDE o problema persiste. Mas eu consegui rodar o programa (que agora vi que esta errado) compilando e ligando os arquivos pelo console mesmo. Vou ter que me inteirar mais sobre o funcionamento do IDE, pois é mas pratico usá-los pra encontrar erros no programa (erros de lógica mas não de depuração).

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva Não conheço o CodeBlocks, mas como você disse na pergunta que criou os arquivos "fora do projeto do IDE, pelo gedit", talvez o CodeBlocks nem saiba que eles existam... Ele *poderia* inspecionar o conteúdo da pasta por qualquer arquivo fonte, mas o mais provável é que ele esteja simplesmente usando um *makefile* ou similar - e se o arquivo criado fora do projeto não entrou no makefile, ele não é considerado na compilação.

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva o código está cheio de problemas, mas você pediu para não falar nada. Tem desde erros bem bobos, que é normal para quem está começando, até erros conceituais. Não sei por onde você está aprendendo e se está supondo coisas por conta própria mas parece que você está usando o que você não tem ideia para que serve. Aprenda tudo o que tem que aprender sobre um recurso antes de usá-lo. IDE não faz milagres. Ela ajuda achar problemas que você entende.

Comment: Realmente, Desconsidera os erros cometidos. Na verdade ainda não tenho pouca experiencia, prática , e conhecimento teórico sobre programação. Creio que a contribuição maior para os erros deve-se ao codigo do arquivo interface.c, no qual possuí códigos que foram copiados do meu livros sem ao menos entendê-los direito.

Answer (score 6):

Creio que você está confundindo o conceito de "linkagem": não é o *source* e o *header* que são linkados, e sim vários arquivos **objeto** que se linkam entre si para formar o executável (ou biblioteca/dll). As etapas de compilação são as seguintes, grosso modo:

1. Cada arquivo fonte é compilado independentemente dos demais arquivos fonte;

   - Se um arquivo usa uma função que não está definida nesse mesmo arquivo, o *header* pode ser usado para dizer "essa função não está aqui mais existe, no futuro ela vai aparecer".
2. O resultado da compilação de cada fonte (i.e. os vários arquivos objeto resultantes da compilação, um por arquivo fonte) são unidos entre si (*"linkados"*) para se produzir o programa completo.

   - Nesse momento sim, um arquivo é cruzado com os outros, e procura-se garantir que toda função utilizada esteja de fato implementada em algum lugar.

Quando se chama o compilador sem especificar uma fase, ele assume que todas as fases devem ser executadas - partindo dos fontes, até chegar no executável. Ou seja, é necessário especificar **todos** os arquivos fonte necessários para a produção do executável, não somente o que contém a função `main`.

Por outro lado, se você deseja compilar cada fonte individualmente, e depois usar uma ferramenta/etapa de linkagem com os arquivos objetos produzidos, use a opção `-c`, e não especifique um arquivo de saída usando a função `-o`:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

O resultado será um arquivo `main.o`, que pode ser usado na etapa de linkagem junto com todos os arquivos `.o` gerados na compilação dos demais fontes.

Comment: Realmente foi uma 'gafe'. Achei que poderia aplicar esse mesmo conceito de ligação para ambos os casos (tanto para os arquivos source e header como para a união de arquivos objetos em um executável). Até pensei em editar a pergunta mas vou deixá-la assim. Bom, vou parar por aqui pra não falar mais idiotices kkk.