# Por que, em C, uma função precisa ser declarada antes de ser usada?

Tags: c#, c, funções, característica-linguagem

Esta [pergunta foi feita no Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/osadpa/permalink/1847359265369592/). Lá é um problema porque não tem espaço para uma boa resposta, não tem como classificar as respostas quanto a sua qualidade de forma adequada, preza-se muito pelo comentário, pela opinião, mais que uma resposta clara e correta. Então fica a pergunta para referência futura sobre a questão.

Segundo a pergunta original o autor veio de C# e está tendo que lidar com C agora.

Ou seja, está traçando um caminho errado, na minha concepção, você primeiro entende o concreto, o simples, o fácil, aí aprende as abstrações que facilitam sua vida. Todo o aprendizado sempre foi calcado nisto e sempre funcionou. Todas tentativas de fazer diferente estão produzindo aberrações, portanto só gente que decoram receitas de bolo e não conseguem criar nada, com critério, com fundamento. Isto em um momento que que estamos transitando para uma sociedade que não precisará mais do que é repetitivo, precisará do criativo, então algo está muito errado, não a toa que esta é a primeira geração na história que na média tem renda menor que seus pais na mesma idade.

Então por que C, ao contrário de C#, precisa declarar a função antes de usar?

[image: Código]

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Somar(double a, double b);

int main() {
    double a, b;
    printf ("Digite a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf ("Digite bi ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("O resultado eh %d", Somar(a, b));
}

double Somar(double a, double b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Muito do que está aqui até foi respondido na postagem original no FB, mas de forma inconsistente e com opções erradas. Aqui é uma tentativa de consolidar o conhecimento de como realmente funciona.

A resposta direta à pergunta é que o compilador C é de [um único passo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler) (e quando falamos de um passo estamos falando do *parsing*, não das outras fases de compilação). Ele faz o *parsing* conforme vai lendo o código e decidindo o que fazer. Isto simplifica o compilador, o torna mais rápido e até a especificação da linguagem é mais simples. Se quiser entender mais sobre [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

C# tem dois passos, primeiro ele lê todo o código e interpreta a estrutura de dados, montando assim as classes e entendendo todos seus membros, e mesmo que algo não possa ser determinado naquele momento ele marca para completar depois. Feito isto ele pode cuidar dos algoritmos que é analisado em um segundo passo.

Claramente isto é mais complicado e mais lento. Nada crítico para uma linguagem criada neste século, mas era um problema para uma linguagem criada há quase 50 anos.

Daí vem a dúvida, por que não muda isso agora? Porque toda a linguagem foi pensada para ser assim, todo código foi escrito baseado nessa premissa, essa mudança traria poucos benefícios e prováveis malefícios ao legado. C tem tanto sucesso por respeito ao legado, seja isto um ponto positivo ou negativo.

E ainda faz parte da filosofia da linguagem de deixar você entender tudo o que está acontecendo, não ficar escondendo muita coisa. Por isso as pessoas deveriam aprender primeiro C para depois aprender outras linguagens, só assim produz desenvolvedores de verdade, ao que está ficando proporcionalmente raro de encontrar, por isso hoje você encontra "desenvolvedores seniores" que não entendem o que estão fazendo, os chamados analfabetos funcionais. Eles produzem aplicações complexas que funcionam, mas só porque estão reproduzindo o que já viram pronto em outro lugar.

Realmente C# dá uma enorme facilidade, mas nada tem a ver com o que se espera de C. A linguagem criada pelo [Dennis Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) tem como objetivo ser um Assembly portável e não uma linguagem *enterprise*.

Alguns dizem que é assim para ser mais rápido, mas isso não torna o código mais rápido, no máximo a compilação é ligeiramente mais rápida. Alias é um mito que C é uma linguagem mais rápida. Ela apenas torna mais óbvia e simples para o programador produzir códigos mais rápidos. Ele não será mais rápido só porque é C. Muita gente produz códigos extremamente lentos em C. E com um detalhe cruel, só são tão lentos porque está escrito em C. A pessoa não entende certas particularidades e comete mais erros que em outras linguagens, por exemplo [usando `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

Mas há um erro na premissa da pergunta e isso é algo que eu vejo quase todo mundo aprendendo errado, muitas vezes porque usam material ruim ou antigo, quando não é culpa do professor. C evoluiu muito, [C hoje preza mais pela legibilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295685/101), e entende que algumas coisas não fazem mais sentido. Este código pode ser melhor escrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Somar(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    double a, b;
    printf ("Digite a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf ("Digite bi ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("O resultado eh %d", Somar(a, b));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fotVKN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uecmxxdk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/DeclarationOrder.c).

A função precisa ser declarada antes, mas pode [definir junto com a declaração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) e virar uma coisa só.

Algumas pessoas disseram lá no Facebook que o correto é colocar a declaração, chamada de protótipo, em um arquivo de cabeçalho. Isso até está correto dependendo do contexto. Não parece o caso, essa função deveria ser usada só aí, então não faz sentido declarar no [*header*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3690/101). O arquivo de cabeçalho só faz sentido para reuso da função. Inclusive em códigos maiores esta função provavelmente deveria ser declarada como [`static`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171410/101) para não ser vista em outro local.

Outro erro é achar que só a declaração deva estar no cabeçalho. Em muitos casos sim, mas há casos que a implementação já deva estar nele, especialmente estas mais simples e que podem ser [linearizadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101). Muitas vezes a pessoa não entende porque precisa usar o [`include`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101) e [*linkar* junto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46297/101) ([Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199892/101)).

A declaração separada da definição só faz sentido quando vai usar um cabeçalho (e isto permite alguns truques que C# não permite, mas vai muito além do escopo da pergunta falar sobre isto), mesmo assim só em alguns casos faz sentido separar; e também faz sentido quando há referência circular, então você precisa primeiro declarar para ela ser usada em outra função, e aí pode definir a função usando uma função definida anteriormente. Não é o caso da pergunta. É importante entender a diferença entre declaração e definição, conforme *link* acima.

Ao contrário do que muitos imaginam em C# também pode fazer isso, e em alguns casos precisa declarar a função separado da definição.

Então alguns dizem que não é obrigatório, e elas estão certas no sentido que eu expliquei. É obrigatório declarar, mas nem sempre precisa declarar separado da definição. Se puder definir antes do uso já está valendo.

A declaração não é só útil, não é só facilitadora, é obrigatória para decidir se o código é válido. Uma linguagem compilada e que se pretende dar um mínimo de robustez precisa indicar se a função pode ser chamada de forma correta.

Alguns disseram para declarar dentro da função `main()` e não está errado, mas não gosto. Acho que declaração de algo de nível superior sempre deveria ser no nível superior. Isto se fizer sentido declarar antes de definir, o que é raro. Pra mim fica assimétrico quando usar com cabeçalho. Em quase todas situações onde não usa cabeçalho basta definir antes, é o mais correto. Se não tem circularidade tem zero benefício declarar antes de definir. Mesmo a ideia de querer o `main()` antes não cola, isto não deixa nada mais legível.

Nada tem a ver com baixo nível (foi dito lá), é possível ser baixo nível e não ter isso e ser alto nível e ter essa necessidade.

Secundariamente falaram sobre o retorno da função. E sim, a função `main()` como ponto de entrada sempre deveria retornar um inteiro para o sistema operacional. Mas não é obrigado escrever esse código de retorno, o compilador geralmente coloca para você se for o padrão. E é possível retornar `void` (alguns compiladores são configurados por padrão para não aceitar isto, mas pode mudar).

Falaram sobre `#region`. Esse mecanismo talvez seja o mais contestado da linguagem, e no fundo é um comentário enfeitado. O IDE é que faz uso útil dele, então pode simular em C, só não deveria ser usado, quando ele ele é necessário tem outros problemas no código.

Tem algumas observações boas lá, como sobre *hoisting*.

Algumas pessoas observaram que o uso de `%d` está errado, acredito que a pessoa deve ter associado a letra com o tipo, mas não, o correto seria `%lf`. O mais correto mesmo em código real é fazer até algo mais sofisticado, mas para exercício está bom.

Mas a questão não é funcionar, é fazer certo, e de preferência idiomaticamente em C, que é diferente de C# e outras linguagens, até mesmo C++ que é ao contrário do que muitos acreditam é uma linguagem completamente diferente.

[image: Fiat 147 detonado andando pelas ruas]

Tem muitos comentários errados lá (até com *likes*), mas não vou falar um por um. E tem maluquices também, sei lá a pessoa deve ter chego do carnaval e postou lá...

Enfim, primeiro tem que aprender a programar, aprender a computação (partindo do princípio que a pessoa já sabe matemática, comunicação e expressão, ciência, tudo importante para programar bem), depois deve aprender linguagens que é a parte fácil e quase irrelevante (um dos maiores computólogos do mundo não tinha um computador), ainda assim, precisa aprender com profundidade, entender de fato o que está fazendo. Eu tento programar prioritariamente em C# hoje, mas só porque tenho escolha, não porque é a única coisa que sei.

Bom, temos que tomar cuidado com as informações que recebemos, especialmente de pessoas aleatórias na internet, mais ainda em sites sem compromisso com qualidade, onde a informalidade seja o padrão. Tem muita informação na internet, mas nem todas são boas. Conteste sempre. Se aprofunde. Siga *links*, procure posições contrárias e preocupe-se caso não encontrar. Leia tudo o que puder. Facebook é provavelmente o pior lugar para se perguntar sobre programação por várias razões. E claro, a pessoa sempre tem o direito de escolha por ser amador, e tem o direito de mesmo ter feito esta escolha reclamar do mercado de trabalho não o valorizar. E para quem não conhece o SOpt, mande críticas, sempre podemos melhorar as respostas, ou podemos ter respostas melhores.

Se quer saber mais ou ficou boiando em alguma coisa, pesquise aqui no site, tem bastante material já avaliado por *experts*.