# Passagem por referência em C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Minha IDE está dando erro na linha:

```
float CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,&conversao);
```

Ela indica que precisa de um parênteses antes do operador `&`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 float horas, minutos, segundos, conversao;
 printf("Digite a hora, minutos e segundos: ");
 scanf("%f %f %f", &horas,&minutos,&segundos);
 float CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,&conversao);
 printf("A quantidade de segundos eh %f !\n", conversao);
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
float CalculaHora(float horas,float minutos,float segundos,float *pConversao){
if (horas > 0){
    horas = horas /3600;
         if (minutos > 0)
         minutos = minutos / 60;
            if (segundos > 0)
            *pConversao = minutos + horas + segundos;}
else {
    if (minutos > 0){
    minutos = minutos / 60;
        if (segundos > 0)
        *pConversao = minutos + segundos;}
            else{
                if (segundos > 0)
                *pConversao = segundos;}
        }

return *pConversao;
 }
```

Pessoal queria dizer que me baseei nesse código, por isso não entendi:

```
void CalculaConceito(float media, char *pConceito){
 if (media >= 6) 
 *pConceito = 'A';
 else 
 *pConceito = 'R'; }
int main() {
 float media;
 char conceito;
 printf("Digite a media: ");
 scanf(" %f", &media);
 CalculaConceito(media, &conceito);
 printf("O conceito e %c !\n", conceito);
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Novamente vou chamar sua atenção para: uma função deve ser definida ou antes da main ou depois da main, desde que sua assinatura (ou prótipo) seja declarada antes da main. Não coloque a assinatura **dentro** da main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, essa linha dentro do `main`:

```
float CalculaHora(horas, minutos, segundos, &conversao);
```

Isso é uma tentativa de **declaração de função**, não deveria estar aí. Nesta linha você deveria estar **chamando** a função.

Um esboço do que seria (no final veremos o código completo):

```
// função CalculaHora (declaração da função)
float CalculaHora(float horas, float minutos, float segundos, float *pConversao) {
    // código que calcula...
}

int main() {
    float horas, minutos, segundos, conversao;
    // printf, scanf...

    // CHAMAR a função
    CalculaHora(horas, minutos, segundos, &conversao);
}
```

Repare que para chamar a função eu não preciso colocar `float` na frente. O `float CalculaHora` é usado na declaração da função para dizer "esta é a função `CalculaHora`, que retorna um `float`". Na hora de chamar, você simplesmente... chama, sem colocar o tipo na frente.

---

Agora a questão do `*` versus `&`.

Na declaração da função você usa `float *pConversao`, pois `pConversao` é um ponteiro para `float` (o asterisco indica isso, que é um ponteiro). Isso quer dizer que a função espera um ponteiro ali: quando você for chamar a função, tem que passar um ponteiro.

Agora no `main`, a variável `conversao` não é um ponteiro: ela é um `float`. Mas para chamar a função `CalculaHora`, você precisa passar um ponteiro para `float`. E como você faz para passar um ponteiro para a variável `float`? Colocando o `&` antes, indicando que você está passando o endereço dela (ou seja, um ponteiro para `float`, que é justamente o que a função `CalculaHora` espera).

---

Dito isso, não faz sentido a função ao mesmo tempo mudar o valor do ponteiro **e** retorná-lo. Se ela já retorna, não precisaria receber o ponteiro.

E pelo que entendi, o cálculo está errado. Se você recebe, por exemplo, 1 hora, 10 minutos e 30 segundos, a quantidade de segundos não seria 4230?

Enfim, voltando: se a função recebe um ponteiro e modifica seu valor dentro dela, não tem porque retornar esse mesmo valor, então poderia ser assim:

```
// void, pois não precisa retornar *pConversao (já que o valor é modificado, então o return é redundante)
void CalculaHora(float horas, float minutos, float segundos, float *pConversao) {
    *pConversao = horas * 3600 + minutos * 60 + segundos;
}

int main() {
    float horas, minutos, segundos, conversao;
    printf("Digite a hora, minutos e segundos: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &horas, &minutos, &segundos);
    CalculaHora(horas, minutos, segundos, &conversao);
    printf("A quantidade de segundos eh %f!\n", conversao);
    return 0;
}
```

Mas se quer que a função retorne o valor, então na verdade nem precisaria de ponteiro:

```
// retorna o valor, então não precisa receber o ponteiro
float CalculaHora(float horas, float minutos, float segundos) {
    return horas * 3600 + minutos * 60 + segundos;
}

int main() {
    float horas, minutos, segundos, conversao;
    printf("Digite a hora, minutos e segundos: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &horas, &minutos, &segundos);

    // variável recebe o valor retornado pela função
    conversao = CalculaHora(horas, minutos, segundos);
    printf("A quantidade de segundos eh %f!\n", conversao);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: simplificou o código, valeu cara, testei a funcao embaixo do main mas nao deu certo, voce sabe porque?

Comment: @Cl2727 Porque em C vc precisa declarar a função antes de usá-la: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/366060/112052

Answer (score 1):

**Entrando apenas no mérito do erro apontado na pergunta**, na linha em que "chama" sua função `main`:

```
float CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,&conversao);
```

Perceba que não está realmente chamando a função (veja o `float` no começo da chamada). Você está fazendo algo próximo a [declaração de protótipo de uma função](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prot%C3%B3tipo_de_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Para que consiga chamar sua função corretamente, **declare seu protótipo com os tipos dos parâmetros no começo do seu arquivo e chame a função posteriormente**. O resultado ficará parecido com o bloco de código abaixo (perceba que não há mais um "float" na chamada):

```
float CalculaHora(float horas, float minutos, float segundos, float *conversao);

int main() {
    float horas, minutos, segundos;
     
    float* conversao = malloc(sizeof(float));
     
    printf("Digite a hora, minutos e segundos: ");
     
    scanf("%f %f %f", &horas,&minutos,&segundos);
     
    CalculaHora(horas, minutos, segundos, conversao);

...
```

No segundo exemplo de código da pergunta, perceba que o argumento que está sendo passado para a função **não é um ponteiro**, e sim um `char`. Por isso seu endereço de memória é passado utilizando o operador `&` que retorna um ponteiro:

```
CalculaConceito(..., &conceito);
```

Com a função recebendo um ponteiro em sua assinatura:

```
void CalculaConceito(float media, char *pConceito)
```

Dessa forma o valor para onde o mesmo aponta pode ser acessado com o operador `*`:

```
*pConceito = 'R';
```

Perceba que a declaração da função não retorna valor algum, tendo `void` em sua assinatura. Isso significa que a variável `conceito` na função `main` está sendo alterada **por referência**, ou seja, alterando a variável que foi passada em sua chamada, sem a necessidade de retornar um valor:

```
 scanf(" %f", &media);
 CalculaConceito(media, &conceito);
 printf("O conceito e %c !\n", conceito);
```

Comment: Ah sim, é que no outro código tava desse jeito, com o  comercial

Comment: Eu editei o código ali no post, se puder ver agradeço Ruan

Comment: @CI2727 editei a resposta para complementar a pergunta.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, então quando é do tipo int dá pra passar o parâmetro através do e comercial? Agora com float e int não tem como?

Comment: Não. Você pode alterar qualquer tipo de valor por referência, o único problema foi o fato de declarar a função (com `float CalculaHora...`) dentro do método `main`. Se tirar o `float` da frente da chamada dela na função `main` e passar ela para começo do arquivo, antes da declaração da função `main`, o código deveria funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Perceba, amigo, que você não está chamando a função: está cometendo um erro de sintaxe, e tenho certeza que deve tê-lo cometido por engano.
Seu código deveria estar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,*conversao);

int main() {
 float horas, minutos, segundos, conversao;
 printf("Digite a hora, minutos e segundos: ");
 scanf("%f %f %f", &horas,&minutos,&segundos);
 float horaCalculada = CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,&conversao);
 printf("A quantidade de segundos eh %f !\n", conversao);
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Perceba que eu mudei a linha que a função estava, agora ela é:

```
   float horaCalculada = CalculaHora(horas,minutos,segundos,&conversao);
```

Além disso, declarei a função antes da main, como deve ser feito após C-99.

Comment: Legal cara, vou testar esse código que você postou, tô sem PC agora, mas eu me baseei no código ali acima, editei meu post